# putty does not allow me to input special chars

Tags: centos, putty

I am having trouble accessing a folder with a very long name with `•` in its name.
seems like every time I try to input `•` the putty window is not parsing the character successfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using putty as the client from a Unix box or a Windows box?  What method are you using to input the character?  What is the output that you see on screen when you try to input it?

Comment: @DonSimon I am using putty to access my Unix VPS, I am on Windows Platform. When I copy `•` from my notepad, then right click on putty it has been converted to `.`

Comment: There are a large number of alternative settings in the Translation panel for Putty...what is currently configured, and what does your Unix box report for $TERM ?

Comment: @DonSimon `[root@xxx ~]# $TERM` is `-bash: xterm: command not found` I haven't done anything to putty to change its config regarding "translation"

Comment: You need to use UTF8 as character set on Unix (see the `LANG` environment variable, I use `en_US.UTF-8`), and you need to configure `putty` to use UTF8 as the remote character set (settings->Window->Translation).